# The probability of getting an event with two coins

Tags: probability

> Two coins are flipped and the results are recorded. Given that one coin lands on a head, find the probability of:
>
> 1. Two heads
> 2. Head and Tail

My turn:

Using the tree diagram, I found that

1. $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$
2. $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$

Are these answers correct?

Comment: You're already given that the first one is heads, so we can ignore that coin, and you simply need to find the probability of the second coin landing heads or tails respectively

Comment: The wording "given that one coin comes up heads" is ambiguous, it could mean "at least one head" in which the answers are $1/3$ and $2/3$ or it could mean "a randomly revealed coin was heads" in which case the answers are $1/2$ and $1/2$. The first interpretation is more common in probability books, but it's still poorly worded in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

No. These are the actual probabilities of the two events  but you are asked to find the conditional probabilities. If $X$ and $Y$ denote the outcomes the first question is to find $P(Y=H|X=H)=\frac  1  2$. The second probability is $P(Y=T|X=H)=\frac  1  2$.

Edit: With the interpretation suggested by joriki in his comment below the first probability turns out to be $\frac {1/4} {1-\frac 1  4}=\frac 1  3$.

Comment: The question does not ask for finding the conditional probability , it asks about the intersection @Kavi Rama

Comment: The phrase 'find probability of $A$ given that $B$ has occured' is interpreted as $P(A|B)$, not $P(A\cap B)$. @HussienMohamed

Comment: The required is the probability of two heads means the probability of the intersection @Kavi

Comment: @HussienMohamed: If you're so sure you know better, I wonder why you're asking a question here.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: You're interpreting "one coin" as "the first coin". Another possible interpretation is that the question asks for $P(Y=H\mid X=H\cup Y=H)$, with "one coin" interpreted as "at least one of the coins". What speaks in favour of that interpretation is that it makes for a more interesting problem. Since "lands on a head" is not proper English, the problem statement seems to be translated (or at least not written by a native speaker), so the unclear formulation "one coin" may well have referred to either possibility in the original.

Comment: @joriki Shouldn't it be $P(X=Y=H|(X=H) \cup (Y=H))$ with that interpretation?

Comment: I am sure of the required not the answer of it @joriki

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Sorry, yes, it should.